# Can I create a sparse tree for where I am now - i.e. make an org-mode sparse tree of the path to point?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The title pretty much says it:
I often want to create a sparse tree
for my current position in the current buffer,
showing all the headings to get to me.

Here's

** WANTED create a sparse tree for where I am now           :orgmode:

I often want to be able to create a sparse tree for where I am now.
It is a bit of a pain to have to create a search C-c //
- but that is my current kluge:

a) insert a unique string like HERE-I-AM

b) C-C // HERE-I-AM
   (org-occur "HERE-I-AM" nil)

Giving something like this

```
** My (org-mode) LOGS                           :top:
** LOGs :log
*** Fri Mar 22 2013
**** DONE org-mode - trying to get calendar to work
***** DONE rewrote docs
     - State "DONE"       from ""           [2013-03-22 Fri 14:49]

    blah blah blah

HERE-I-AM

** ...NEXT Daily Log
```

This is obviously unsatisfactory.
e.g. may not have write permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do what you want:

```lisp
(defun my-org-sparse-tree ()
  "Create an org sparse tree showing only point"
  (interactive)
  (org-overview)      ;; Hide everything
  (org-show-context)) ;; Show context around point
```

Answer (score 1):

I quickly wipped something up that might be what you want, or at least close:

```
(defun tr/path-sparse-tree ()
  "sparse tree to the current buffer position"
  (interactive)
  (setq pathmarker "Eeshoo9OomeiRaix") ;; random string obtained from
                                       ;; pwgen, probably a unique marker
                                       ;; in any org document...
  (save-excursion 
    (insert pathmarker)
    (org-occur pathmarker))
  (delete-char 16))
```

I'm not a emacs-lisp practitioner per se, but my quick tests were promising with respect to your problem description. At least it's your current kludge automated ;-).